# Can I blend high-protein (baking) flour and 00 flour to approximate plain (AP) flour?

Tags: flour

The high-protein flour has 11.5% protein — the 00 flour has unknown protein content. I understand that "00" is a statement of the flour's grain size and not its protein level, but I assume that there's a normal range or expectation for the protein content of 00 flour.

So, would it be suitable to blend the two in some proportion to obtain something substitutable for AP flour?

Comment: What protein content are you expecting for AP flour?  Because the AP flour I use *is* 11.5%.

Comment: What do you want to use it for? The right question may be whether you can use high protein flour for a particular application.

Answer (score 1):

First, in both the US and Australia, 00 flour has about the same protein content as AP flour, so you can use it instead, keeping in mind that it's more finely milled. To answer your broader question, yes, you can definitely combine flours together to approximate AP flour (keeping in mind that protein content in AP flour will range from brand to brand). In the US:

- cake flour has low protein content (7-9%)
- AP flour has medium protein content (10-12%)
- bread flour has high protein content (13-16%)

In Australia and other countries the flour percentages may differ from my chart above. I believe Australia has lower protein content in the US in general for AP flour, and 00 flour is also lower, but within the same range as AP flour there.

Comment: I know what you are saying but I think your answer is a bit localized. In the UK where I currently live and other parts of the world AP flour usually has a lower protein content, but it is pretty variable topping at 11%, bread (aka strong) flour is usually between 12 and 13%. There's extra-strong flour which pumps the gluten content even more, which is usually somewhere around 14--15%

Comment: GdD, my answer to the question is correct that you can combine flours if you have a higher-protein flour and lower protein flour to make an AP flour. In doing a quick scan of the Internet, what I'm finding is that the ranges I put in my answer seem to be correct even in the UK, but I haven't been exhaustive in my search. Every manufacturer is going to be different, and this isn't meant to be an almanac of flour, just a general answer to the question. If you believe you have a good source for correct protein flour content around the world, why don't you publish that as an additional answer?

Comment: there's no need to be defensive, the point I am making is that it may be worth qualifying your answer with where you are talking about in the world. That's common practice on this site as it often makes a big difference.

Comment: Didn't mean to be defensive, and I get your point. I have updated my original answer to be a bit broader as to region and to include OP's country. I still think if you have the time to provide helpful information about flour content around the world you should do so.